# margins.plot: using the 'which' argument to choose which margins to include in plot

Tags: r, marginal-effects

I am trying to plot [marginal effects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/margins.pdf) in r based on a logistic regression. For example:

```
data <- mtcars
mod <- glm(am ~ cyl + hp + wt + mpg, family = binomial, data = data)

library(margins)
marg <- margins(mod, atmeans = TRUE)
summary(marg)
```

I can run the [margins plot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/margins/versions/0.3.0/topics/plot.margins) command:

```
plot(marg)
```

which plots marginal effects and confidence intervals for all of the IVs. I only want to include in the plot `cyl` and `hp`, my explanatory variables of interest. According to r documentation, this can be accomplished using the 'which' argument, which takes a character vector. However, the documentation doesn't say how to use this argument. Does anyone know how to use the 'which' argument to ask margins.plot to plot only select marginal effects? Unfortunately, the margins plot help page, linked above, does not have any examples.

[plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4fz.png)

Comment: What is `margins`? Please be explicit when reference non-base functions. Additionally, I suggest you base the question off of a package dataset (base R or from where-ever you get `margins`) or include some sample data and regress/plot with that sample.

Comment: I count seven different packages with functions named `margins`: it's rather unlikely that they are all the same funciotn. You need to say which one of those is being used. Best would be to edit your question to put a `library( . )` call at the top of your code. Possibilities: (ltm, margins, oglmx, adabag, reshape2, PivotR, discreteRV). And look at the help page examples for test case (and also edit to include that code.) No comments. I repeat: _no_ comments.

Comment: thanks @r2evans for the tips. I've updated my question to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Before plotting, we can specify variables of interest with the `variables` option within the `margins()`function.

```
mod <- glm(am ~ cyl + hp + wt + mpg, family=binomial, data=mtcars)

library(margins)
marg <- margins(mod, variables=c("cyl", "hp"))

plot(marg)
```

#### *Gives:*

[image]